# Loading native COM DLLs in 64bit environment

Tags: c++, com, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit, 32-bit

I have a 32bit/64bit COM DLLs in C++: mycom32.dll, mycom64.dll. Both of them are **exactly the same** but mycom32.dll is compiled for 32bit and mycom64.dll is compiled for 64bit.
That means that BOTH DLLs have the same UUID and the same CLSID!

Now, sometimes I want to use this COM from 32bit processes and sometimes I want to use this COM from 64bit processes.

Is it possible to load the correct DLL without creating two different CLSIDs and check during runtime if the process is 32bit/64bit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be possible to register both of them without issue; this is part of what [Registry Redirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384253%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is supposed to solve.

Here's a more [detailed explanation](http://mariusbancila.ro/blog/2010/11/04/32-bit-and-64-bit-com-servers/) of how this works.

Comment: Cool.  I would have assumed you would need different CLSIDs.